# How to count number of clicks on button and save in MySql database? The clicks in a new session should be added to the existing value

Tags: java, jquery, mysql, hibernate, jsp

This is the DAO I have created:

```
public Poll updatePoll(int id){
        Session s = factory.getCurrentSession();
        Transaction t = s.beginTransaction();
    
        Poll poll = (Poll) s.get(Poll.class, id);
        Citizen citizen = (Citizen) s.get(Citizen.class, 1);
        List<Poll> list = citizen.getPolledList();
    
        boolean check = list.contains(poll);
        if(!check){
            Query q = s.createSQLQuery("update Poll set poll_count = poll_count + 1 where poll_id = id");
            q.executeUpdate();
            s.update(poll);
        }else{
            return poll;
        }
        s.close();
        return poll;        
    }
```

This is the `Action` created:

```
    public String submitVote(){
        ServletContext ctx = ServletActionContext.getServletContext();
        ProjectDAO dao = (ProjectDAO)ctx.getAttribute("DAO");
        Poll poll = dao.updatePoll(poll_id);
    
        String flag = "error";
    
        if (poll != null){
            ServletActionContext.getRequest().getSession(true).setAttribute("POLL", poll);
            flag = "voted";
        }
        return flag;
    }
```

I know I have been going horribly wrong and the code I'm posting might be utter rubbish. But I hope the intent is clear, thus if possible please lent me a helping hand. My project is mainly in JSP (Struts 2), jQuery and MySQL 5.1, so please do not suggest PHP codes as I've found earlier.

Comment: What is your specific issue?

Answer (score 0):

The framework is used to wrap the servlet stuff from user, you should use its features if you want doing something like

```
ServletActionContext.getRequest().getSession(true)
```

But

```
Map m = ActionContext.getContext().getSession();
```